# How to properly pass a dict of key/value args to kwargs?

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I have the following:

```
class Foo:
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
                print kwargs

settings = {foo:"bar"}
f = Foo(settings)
```

This generates an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 12, in <module>
    settings = {foo:"bar"}
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

How do I properly pass a dict of key/value args to kwargs?

Comment: What is `foo` supposed to be? You haven't defined it, as the error message correctly says.

Comment: as difference of javascript python allows to do the following `foo="hello";settings = {foo:"bar"}` creating a dict `{"hello":"bar"}` in [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) there is Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`**kw` call convention](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls):

```
f = Foo(**settings)
```

This works on any callable that takes keyword arguments:

```
def foo(spam='eggs', bar=None):
    return spam, bar

arguments = {'spam': 'ham', 'bar': 'baz'}
print foo(**arguments)
```

or you could just call the function with keyword arguments:

```
f = Foo(foo="bar")
foo(spam='ham', bar='baz')
```

Your error is unrelated, you didn't define `foo`, you probably meant to make that a string:

```
settings = {'foo': 'bar'}
```

Comment: `settings = dict(foo='bar')` is another way to construct a dictionary without adding quotes to the keys.